# Action result and button Authorization in asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079552/Custom-Roles-Based-Access-Control-RBAC-in-ASP-NE) for role based access control in asp.net identity 2.
In there if a user has not permission for a specific controller then it redirect to an unauthorized page.

Here is code

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    try
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //Redirect user to login page if not yet authenticated.  This is a protected resource!
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", returnUrl = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.FilePath }));
        }
        else
        {
            string requiredPermission = String.Format("{0}-{1}", filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName, filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);

            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.HasPermission(requiredPermission) & !filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsSysAdmin())
            {

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "Index" }, { "controller", "Unauthorised" } });
            }
        }
    }
```

But I don't want to redirect to another page. Is there any way unauthorized user is not capable of see that button which action is not allowed for that user?

As I am new in asp.net identity I can't understand how I do it. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include a link to the tutorial you are mentioning?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg i include link .

Comment: So the question is: how to hide /show actions from users based on permissions?